# Inserting page break using Aspose.cell OR Aspose.Excel

Tags: c#, .net

We have a reporting project where in we use the .NET framework to create excel reports on the fly. The different components that are used are System Namespace, Aspose.Cell and Aspose.Excel

We have a report where we execute a certain set of command in a loop. After each loop execution we need to insert a page break. Currently, we use System.Environment to insert line breaks, but I don't see any similar method for page break. Also, I read some where that the Aspose.cell latest version supports page break, but we are using version 4.7.1.0

Can someone advise me on how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have ever never worked with Aspose before, I did a quick search and found that there was a VerticalPageBreak object in the [object model](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Aspose.Cells+Object+Model) as shown on the website:

> Each Worksheet object contains a VerticalPageBreakCollection object. 
> A VerticalPageBreak object is used to create a vertical page break in the worksheet.

The best way to insert page breaks seems to be by using the VerticalPageBreak Class:

```
excel.Worksheets[0].VerticalPageBreaks.Add("G5");
```

[Here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/VerticalPageBreak+Class) is a reference to the VerticalPageBreak Class. 
This should take care of vertical page breaks.